# Optimal sizes to display X picture boxes in an given space

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I searched before posting but couldn't find anything close to my issue.

What I need to figure out is how to come with the optimal width and height of picture boxes (with a 4:3 ratio), given the required number of boxes to be displayed, and the available space.

Now, it's not as simple as a just dividing the available space by the number of required boxes, because the available space is not a uniform shape, but rather two rectangles of which size may vary (see this picture, it's the **a+b** space).

If fact, I have tried starting from there with the following code :

```
    Private Sub LayoutSnapshots()
    Dim lTotalSpace As Single, lSnapsize As Single, sXSize As Single, sYSize As Single
    Dim I As Integer, J As Integer, X As Integer = 0, Y As Integer = 0, oPic As PictureBox

    ' bSnaps is the number of picture boxes to be displayed
    If stSetting.bSnaps = 0 Then Exit Sub

    ' oSnaps is a List(Of PictureBoxe) to groupp the actual picture boxes
    If oSnaps.Count > 0 Then
        For Each oCtrl As PictureBox In oSnaps
            Me.Controls.Remove(oCtrl)
        Next
    End If
    oSnaps.Clear()

    ' Calculating the a+b space shown on the picture
    lTotalSpace = ((Me.ClientSize.Height - MenuStrip1.Height) * Me.ClientSize.Width) - ((picPreview.Width + iMargin) * (picPreview.Height + iMargin))

    If lTotalSpace < 1 Then
        MsgBox("Window is too small. Please adjust one of these settings : Window size, Snapshots count, Live free view size.", MsgBoxStyle.ApplicationModal Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'calculating a single picture's size by dividing total space by the number of snaps
    lSnapsize = Math.Truncate(lTotalSpace / stSetting.bSnaps)

    'Calculating Height and Width, with 4:3 ratio
    sXSize = Math.Truncate(Math.Sqrt((4 * lSnapsize) / 3))
    sYSize = Math.Truncate(Math.Sqrt((3 * lSnapsize) / 4))

    For I = 1 To stSetting.bSnaps
        If oPic IsNot Nothing Then oPic = Nothing
        oPic = New PictureBox
        oPic.BackColor = Color.White
        oPic.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        oPic.Size = New Size(sXSize - 1, sYSize - 1)
        oPic.Location = New Point(X * sXSize, (Y * sYSize) + MenuStrip1.Height)

        oSnaps.Add(oPic)
        ' Layed them successively on screen, need to optimize this
        If ((X + 2) * sXSize) > (Me.ClientSize.Width) Then
            X = 0
            Y += 1
        Else
            X += 1
        End If
    Next

    For Each oCtrl As PictureBox In oSnaps
        Me.Controls.Add(oCtrl)
    Next
End Sub
```

But obviously with all the possibilities of windows resizing, I couldn't think of any practical way to optimize it.

[image]

I am pretty sure this has to do with "operation research", as I recall we did optimization problems like this back then when I was a student, but I'm not sure how to actually model this or even if it is solvable by linear programming.

Comment: @StephenKennedy You should include a reason for your edit. Plus, other than adding the picture to the post (which I could not do because I lack reputation points), all other edit where not necessary and/or are arguably removing key information from my post. And yet you brought no help to my issue. And no, I'm not here to get into a row.

Comment: Feel free to roll back my edit but I'd be interested to know what key information I removed. That you're new? That there is a deadline? How is any of that relevant to the question?

Comment: I should thank you for editing first because I forgot to do that. Well, thank you. But yes, that information maybe relevant. I'm particularly thinking about the part precising that I only need somebody to point me in the right direction, which might make it easier for people to  provide short answers instead of complete solutions. At least, that's how I thought about it.

Comment: Thanks for the cordial reply. I felt that "since I should be delivering this app soon, I don't have quite a lot of time to do the appropriate research" might get you some negative attention as its effectively saying "do my work for me" and that doesn't go down well here at all. I'm honestly not sure whether saying you just wanted to be pointed in the right direction would be beneficial or not. Its your question so feel free to hit "edit" and put it back in. Read this if you haven't already: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Here's the discussion wrt salutations and thanks, with the consensus being that they are noise and can be edited out http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts Also, since you were wondering why I edited your question and didn't provide any further help; StackOverflow is user moderated and I found your question in the "Help and improvement" queue, which means other users have indicated it needed to be edited. I hope that all helps.

Comment: Well, thank you anyway. You've quite some reputation here so you probably know better about the form. I'll keep it like that. And of course I'm not asking people to do the work for me, I'm rather looking for help doing it, because i've already been messing with some ideas I got but I have no success so far. I can post the code of that If it's required too.

Comment: Oh yes, if you've already tried to resolve the issue and have some code which didn't work, post it with some commentary! Good luck!

Comment: Nice. +1 from me. Will disappear now, cheers.

Comment: It is an NP-hard problem, you can't find the optimum in a reasonable amount of time.  Google "2d bin packing problem".

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking into it right now. I've also been messing white a kinda "brute force" method, by doing the division (as shown in code above), then counting how many I can fit into each of the spaces (a, and b). If I can fit as many as required, then I found my solution (although it's not quite THE optimum), otherwise, I'll make the box dimension smaller and loop until I find a solution. Still messing with it though. I'll be also checking your suggestion and posting back if any works.

Comment: Just check the NP-Hard thingy. Yeah, I will probably try making the method above work instead, as finding the optimum seems to be something out of my knowledge league right now.

Comment: I figured it out, the approach above worked well. Updating the main post in a second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured this out. The solution is kind of a "brute force" technique, it doesn't always return the optimum BUT the error is merely a few pixels. I used the code below, it works but it might need further optimization in terms of spacing. I couldn't comment on everything since I have a time pressure right now, but still wanted to share the answer, so just take some time to analyze it :

```
Private Sub LayoutSnapshots()

    Dim sA As Single, sB As Single, sTotal As Single, sSnap As Single, sWidth As Single, sHeight As Single
    Dim iCount As Integer = stSetting.bSnaps, iFit As Integer, iX As Integer, iY As Integer, iYg As Integer, I As Integer
    Dim rA As Rectangle, rB As Rectangle, oPic As PictureBox, lpLoc As New List(Of Point), pLoc As New Point

    Static bWarn As Boolean

    Dim gPic As Graphics

    ' bSnaps is the number of picture boxes to be displayed
    If stSetting.bSnaps = 0 Then Exit Sub

    ' If controls already on form, remove them and start form scratch
    If oSnaps.Count > 0 Then
        For Each oCtrl As PictureBox In oSnaps
            Me.Controls.Remove(oCtrl)
        Next
    End If

    ' oSnaps is a List(Of PictureBox) grooping the picture boxes. Clear it for now
    oSnaps.Clear()

    'sA, sB are the sizes of spaces A and B respectively
    sA = (Me.ClientSize.Width * (Me.ClientSize.Height - (MenuStrip1.Height + picPreview.Height + iMargin)))
    sB = ((Me.ClientSize.Width - (picPreview.Width + iMargin)) * (picPreview.Height + iMargin))

    ' Total free space
    sTotal = sA + sB

    ' This condition is important. It ensures there is at least one solution
    ' before entering the loops bellow. Otherwise we might get stuck in an infinite loop
    If (sTotal < (stSetting.bSnaps * stSetting.bSnaps)) Then

        ' bWarn is a static boolean. Since this Sub is called from Form_Resize event, we 
        ' want to warn the user only once when there is no space. 
        ' Otherwise it becomes annoying.

        If bWarn Then MsgBox("Window is too small. Please adjust one of these settings : Window size, Snapshots count, Live free view size.", MsgBoxStyle.ApplicationModal Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        bWarn = False
        Exit Sub
    End If

    bWarn = True

    Me.UseWaitCursor = True

    Do

        'rA, rB are the bounding rectangles of spaces A and B respectively
        rA = New Rectangle(0, MenuStrip1.Height, Me.ClientSize.Width, Me.ClientSize.Height - (MenuStrip1.Height + picPreview.Height + iMargin))
        rB = New Rectangle(0, picPreview.Top, Me.ClientSize.Width - (picPreview.Width + iMargin), picPreview.Height + iMargin)

        ' A single box's size
        sSnap = Math.Truncate(sTotal / iCount)

        ' Width and Height with 4:3 aspect ratio.
        sWidth = Math.Truncate(Math.Sqrt((4 * sSnap) / 3))
        sHeight = Math.Truncate(Math.Sqrt((3 * sSnap) / 4))

        ' iFit keeps track of how many boxes we could fit in total
        iFit = 0
        iYg = 0
        lpLoc.Clear()

        ' It would be a bit too long to explain the next block of code and I have a deadline to meet
        ' I'll comenting on that later
        iX = 0
        iY = 0
        Do While (rA.Height >= ((sHeight * (iY + 1)) + 1))
            If (((iX + 1) * sWidth) + 1) <= rA.Width Then
                iFit += 1
                lpLoc.Add(New Point(rA.X + ((iX * sWidth) + 1), rA.Y + ((iYg * sHeight) + 1)))
                iX += 1
            Else
                iX = 0
                iY += 1
                iYg += 1
            End If
        Loop

        'Add unused space from A to B.
        rB.Height = rB.Height + (rA.Height - ((iYg * sHeight) + 1))

        iX = 0
        iY = 0
        Do While (rB.Height >= ((sHeight * (iY + 1)) + 1))
            If (((iX + 1) * sWidth) + 1) <= rB.Width Then
                iFit += 1
                lpLoc.Add(New Point(rB.X + ((iX * sWidth) + 1), rA.Y + ((iYg * sHeight) + 1)))
                iX += 1
            Else
                iX = 0
                iY += 1
                iYg += 1
            End If
        Loop

        Application.DoEvents()

        iCount += 1

    Loop While iFit < stSetting.bSnaps

    ' Add controls to form. Lay them one next to each other.
    iX = 0
    iY = 0
    For I = 1 To stSetting.bSnaps
        If oPic IsNot Nothing Then oPic = Nothing
        oPic = New PictureBox

        oPic.BackColor = Color.Cyan
        oPic.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        oPic.Size = New Size(sWidth - 1, sHeight - 1)
        oPic.Location = lpLoc(I - 1)

        ' Just for debugging, displays index of each box inside it.
        oPic.Image = New Bitmap(oPic.Width, oPic.Height)
        gPic = Graphics.FromImage(oPic.Image)
        gPic.DrawString(I, New Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Red, New Point(0, 0))

        oSnaps.Add(oPic)
        Me.Controls.Add(oSnaps.Last)
    Next

    'Catch Ex As Exception

    'Finally
    Me.UseWaitCursor = False
    'End Try
End Sub
```

P.S : Anyone please feel free to add more explanation to the code if you want.